# why does my app not display the api response properly

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

so my api is returning the correct info from my sqlite db ( i think)

this is the response i get when i just do {{ vendor }}
`[ { "id": 1, "vendor_name": "pip" }, { "id": 3, "vendor_name": "test1" } ]`

but when i add the ".vendor_name" to the v-for in my template it disappears

is the api response in the wrong format or am i assigning it to the "ref" wrong?

im new to vue and im trying to figure out why this is happening
any help is greatly appreciated

```
<script >
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup () {
        const vendors = ref()

        const loadvendors = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/vendors')
        vendors.value = response.data
        }

        loadvendors()
       
        return {
            vendors
        }
    }
}


</script>

<template>
    
        <h1>Vendors</h1>
        
        <li v-for="vendor in vendors">{{ vendor.vendor_name }}</li>


</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, all i had to do was use

`<li v-for="vendor in vendors.vendors" :key="vendors.id">{{ vendor.vendor_name }}</li>`

instead of

`<li v-for="vendor in vendors" :key="vendors.id">{{ vendor.vendor_name }}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

I think. You should load data from api onMounted() and you should set any value in ref([]) or ref(null);

Comment: im getting this error now ```[Vue warn]: Property "vendors" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <VendorPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>```

Comment: Can I see your code again?

Comment: https://codepen.io/yehudafreedman/pen/vYjBKGe

Comment: try to use below code `setup () {
  const vendors = ref([])
  onMounted(async() => {
    const response= await axios.get('url')
    vendors.value = response.data
  })
  return {
    vendors
  }
}`